# Constraints are not expanding my View on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I created my view as so :

```
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 1000)

    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints    = false
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

And then I added these constraints :

```
    // Constraint ScrollView
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

    // Constraint ContainerView
    scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

And this :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.frame    = view.bounds
    containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
}
```

But when I change the orientation, the width of the `containerView` remains the same. How can I ensure that the width expands to the width of the `scrollView` to it's new layout?

Comment: did you set a fix width ? Maybe from your main.storyboard ?

Comment: @Thomasa I updated my response above.  Perhaps it is the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method that is overriding it somehow? To be clear, the `scrollView`'s width expands properly, just not it's `containerView`.

Comment: `view` is `containerView`? If you use the view hierarchy debugging tool, does it appear to show that your constraints have been appropriately communicated?

Comment: @Tommy is that visual? I'm doing all this programmatically. Sorry, I'm a complete beginner.. :(

Comment: you must also add constraints of container view to scrollView

Comment: @EleneAkhvlediani I did, and updated my answer above but no changes.

Comment: try this 
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

Comment: @Trip yes! Reference to e.g. https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6 is probably the quickest way to provide some of the details in a mere comment box. Short version: run app, hit button in Xcode, inspect views as actually on screen, including lists of constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```
scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

with

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

This uses the width and height of the scroll view instead of stretching the container view to the right side and bottom of the scroll view. It seems to work much better. I also added the constraint to a common ancestor, as per the docs but it also works by adding to scrollView, so take your choice whether you want to add all constraints to the view instead of the scrollView or not.

### Further note

In iOS 8 and later you can simply activate your constraints instead of adding them to your view.

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
```

In iOS 9, which I like even more you can use anchors, e.g.

```
scrollView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
```

You don't need to do anything in layoutSubviews. The translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property should indeed be set to false NOT true.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. I definitely need to study a few more hours on NSLayoutConstraints, but your answer didn't seem to render results. At best, the text stays centered, but the UILabel width doesn't expand to these new constraints. Thanks so much for your answer though! Hopefully I'll have a solution soon, and I imagine I'll come back to your response, and realize you had the right answer all along.

Comment: Here is some [working code](https://gist.github.com/sketchytech/95c632b5b3f71e7b1fe2) to make a UILabel fill the screen area inside a scroll view. Also see [a list of posts](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Fear%20and%20Loathing%20in%20Auto%20Layout) that I wrote on Auto Layout. This one in particular being about [programmatic constraints](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/auto-layout-programmatic-constraints.html).

Comment: !!! Yes!!!! Thank you so much good sir! This absolutely solves it! And thanks so much for the reading material. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should also add these constraints

```
containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

Comment: This returns  `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:`

Comment: I tried adding your before comment `containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` but that returns the same error..